# Creating arrow head matching size (or lwd) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

To draw arrows in ggplot, I use geom_segment and arrow=arrow().
I would like the arrow head size to match the segment width (or size).
However, arrow does not recognize variables directly from the data argument in ggplot and one must specify data.frame containing the variable using the $ operator. This causes a disjunct between the values used for plotting the line and those used for plotting the arrow head (the largest arrow head can be on the thinest segment).

Example:

```
d <- structure(list(Process = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("First", "Second"), class = "factor"), 
x.sink = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2), y.sink = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), x.source = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3), y.source = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1), offset = c(1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1), 
Std.Flux = c(0.179487179487179, 0.170940170940171, 0.944444444444444, 
0.0854700854700855, 0.726495726495726, 0.128205128205128, 
0.213675213675214, 0.213675213675214, 0.128205128205128, 
0.106837606837607, 1)), .Names = c("Process", "x.sink", "y.sink", 
"x.source", "y.source", "offset", "Std.Flux"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))


p <- qplot(data=d,
           #alpha=I(0.4),
           colour=Process,
           size=Std.Flux,
           xlim=c(0,4),
           ylim=c(0,3),
           x=x.source+as.numeric(Process)/10,
           y=y.source+as.numeric(Process)/10,
           xend=x.sink+as.numeric(Process)/10,
           yend=y.sink+as.numeric(Process)/10,
           geom="segment",
           arrow = arrow(type="closed",
                         length = unit(d$Std.Flux,"cm")))
print(p)
```

[image: Disjunct arrow heads]

Any suggestions?

Comment: i reckon it's an oversight; worth posting a feature request on github

Comment: Voting to close - Reporting bug which must have been fixed in the last 8 years - not reproducible any more (see reprex in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars

arrow_pos <- data.frame(y = 250)

ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) +
  geom_bar(width = .4, stat="identity", fill="darkblue")  +
  geom_segment(data=arrow_pos, 
               aes(x=1.526, xend=1.01, y=y + 90.02, yend=y + 0.25),
               arrow=arrow(length=unit(4.2, "mm")), lwd=2,
               color="black") +
  geom_segment(data=arrow_pos, 
               aes(x=1.525, xend=1.01, y=y + 90, yend=y + 0.25),
               arrow=arrow(length=unit(4, "mm")), lwd=1,
               color="gold2") +
  annotate("text", x=2.39, y=360, 
           label='This arrow points to the highest MPG.') +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,400)) +
  xlab('CYL') + ylab('MPG')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Etienne Low-Décarie - Hi, are you still looking for an answer to this question or has it been solved? If this answers your question, please select it as a solution to help the community know it's been solved and to help others find their answer even faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Must have been fixed in the last 8 years :)

Here translated into a call to ggplot()

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(colour=Process, size=Std.Flux)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x.source+as.numeric(Process)/10,
                   y=y.source+as.numeric(Process)/10,
                   xend=x.sink+as.numeric(Process)/10,
                   yend=y.sink+as.numeric(Process)/10),
                   arrow = arrow(type="closed",
                         length = unit(d$Std.Flux,"cm")))
```

[image]